# How to find such modular division answer?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $x = a\bmod M, y = b\bmod M$, where $M$ is a prime number.

I do not know $a$ and $b$, but I know $x$ and $y$ and $M$.

Is it possible to calculate $ (a/b)\bmod M $?

Sorry if it sounds too junior

Comment: If $M$ is prime and $(b,M)=1$, then $b$ is invertible$\bmod M$, so you can take $a\cdot b^{-1}\bmod M$

Comment: @sharding4 but I do not know $a$, $b$,  I only know $x$, $y$...

Comment: They're the same$\bmod M$.  You should be able to use the Euclidean algorithm to find an inverse for $y\bmod M$.  Then $x(y)^{-1}\equiv a(b)^{-1}\bmod M$

Comment: Let $a = 22, b = 8, M = 3$, then $ (a/b) mod M = 0 $, but $ (x/y) mod M $ = $ (1*2) mod M $ = 2 ...

Comment: $a/b\bmod M \equiv 0$ is incorrect.  Why do you say that?  Look at $2\cdot 8 -3\cdot 5 =1$ which tells you that $2$ is an inverse for $8\bmod 3$

Comment: @sharding4 oh man I am dumb. You are right...sorry & thanks!

Comment: We all get a little smarter as we figure out our mistakes.